# Obtener un string entre el primer parentisis que abre y el ultimo que cierra

Tags: php, str-replace

Necesito obtener  un string entre el primer parentisis que abre y el ultimo que cierra, para luego realizar un str_replace entre esos parentesis, finalmente realizar un explode para obetener los campos.

Algo como esto:

```
$string = field1,field2,(if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_)) as field3,field4;
```

**La función a llamar tiene que obtener esta parte del codigo. (if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_)) luego:**

```
$string_btwn_parenthesis = [(if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_))]; <- obtained by function
```

*Quiero obtener esto -->(if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_))<--

no -->(if(isnull(table.id_)<--,1,table.id_))*

```
$string_replaced = str_replace($string_btwn_parenthesis," ",$string);

$arrayfields = explode(",",$string_replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es utilizar [expresiones regulares](http://www.igdonline.com/blog/rapido-y-completo-expresiones-regulares-en-php/). Suponiendo que he entendido bien tu pregunta:

```
$test = "[(if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_))];";
$matches = [];
$values = preg_match('/(?<=\()(.+)(?=\))/is', $test, $matches);
$result = explode(',', $matches[1]);
```

Lo que producirá un resultado como:

```
Array
(
    [0] => if(isnull(table.id_)
    [1] => 1
    [2] => table.id_)
)
```

Comment: Supongamos:
la variable $string es en realidad una consulta SQL,  a travez de un substr obtuve los campos a partir del select hasta el from, seria por lo tanto esto:
field1,field2,(if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_)) as field3,field4

Quiero capturar los campos y almacenarlos en un array, esto lo hago con un explode, entonces: $array_campos = explode(",",$sql_campos);

El problema esta antes de esto ultimo, al tener condiciones especiales en los campos bien sea ifnull, concat, sum etc. el explode estaria tomando las comas internas (if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_))

Comment: Creo que con expresiones regulares también puedes hacerlo. Lo que pasa que se complica algo más. ¿Van a llegarte las expresiones siempre con paréntesis? ¿Que te parece intentar usar un [*parser* de SQL](https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser)?

Comment: un parser seria un extremo que no quiero llegar.. podria ser una expresion regular pero tendria que tomar en todo caso DESDE ACA (if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_)) as HASTA ACA, utilizando preg_replace, eliminando todo ese string para luego poder realizar el explode de comas y poder agarrar el nombre del campo recibido por alias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con la siguiente expresión regular:

`^[^\(]+|[^\)]+$|([a-zA-Z]\w*+(?:[.][a-zA-Z]\w*+)?)(?!\s*['"(])`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zzVPFd/1/).

Debería capturarte las columnas que haya dentro del grupo de paréntesis más externo.

La expresión regular guardará las columnas en el grupo de captura 1. Tienes que comprobar que este grupo tenga contenido, y si lo tiene, resultará ser una columna y ya haces lo que quieras con ella.

[Aquí](https://www.ideone.com/CqaAwf) tienes un ejemplo imprimiendo las columnas

```
<?php

$string = "field1,field2,(if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_)) as field3,field4;";

preg_match_all(
   "/^[^\(]+|[^\)]+$|([a-zA-Z]\w*+(?:[.][a-zA-Z]\w*+)?)(?!\s*['\"(])/"
  ,$string
  ,$matches
 );

$i = 0;
foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
  if (!empty($match)) {
    print($matches[0][$i]) . "\n";
  }
  $i++;
}
```